# System.Linq.Dynamic - use SELECT inside WHERE statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic-linq

I need to generate SQL query dynamically using System.Linq.Dynamic like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[FromRevision] AS [FromRevision], 
    [Extent1].[Field1] AS [Field1], 
    [Extent1].[TillRevision] AS [TillRevision], 
    [Extent1].[Field2] AS [Field2], 
    [Extent1].[Date1] AS [Date1], 
    [Extent1].[LastChangeDate] AS [LastChangeDate], 
    [Extent1].[Field3] AS [Field3]
    FROM [log].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (([Extent1].[FromRevision] <= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[TillRevision] > @p__linq__1) AND 
    ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [log].[MyTable] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Field1] = [Extent1].[Field1]) AND ([Extent2].[FromRevision] <= @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent2].[TillRevision] > @p__linq__3)
    )))
```

The code above was generated by Linq for generic IQueryable, like this:

```
query.Where(o =>
            //ADDED
            (   o.FromRevision <= tillRevision &&
                o.TillRevision > tillRevision &&
                !query.Any(o1 =>
                    o1.Uid == o.Uid &&
                    o1.FromRevision <= fromRevision &&
                    o1.TillRevision > fromRevision)
            )
```

But is it possible to get same result, same SELECT result using Dynamic Linq and not generic IQueryable?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Dynamic Linq and not build an expression yourself?

Comment: Yes, I don't know at designtime what types will come to this constructor, filters and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the optional `params object[] values` argument to pass some parameters to the dynamic query (like `query`, `tillRevision` and `fromRevision`). Then you can refer to them inside the string as `@0`, `@1`, `@2` based on their position.

For accessing the current range variable in scope you could use `it` or nothing. It will be the equivalent of your `o` variable. The important detail is that when you enter a nested scope (like your `Any`), inside that scope `it` or nothing will refer to what your `o1` variable does. In order to access the outer variable, you should use `outerIt`.

Here is the Dynamic LINQ equivalent of your query, hope you'll figure out how to build it dynamically:

```
var result = query.Where(
    "FromRevision <= @0 && TillRevision > @0 && !@2.Any(Uid == outerIt.Uid && FromRevision <= @1 && TillRevision > @1)",
    tillRevision, // @0
    fromRevision, // @1,
    query // @2
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get exception like "No property or field 'outerIt' exists in type 'MyType' ".. It seems that parser convert my query parameter to a real objects collection and don't know what "outerIt" is. Any ideas? I've found that there is some problems with outerIt statement, but now sure that it's my case..

Comment: I don't know, it worked for me. May be you are on older version? I've tested with System.Linq.Dynamic by Microsoft, v1.0.6

Comment: Apparently outerIt is an extension to the original Dynamic library that some versions implement, the nuget version 1.07 should have it, though it looks to me like it may still have a bug in its implementation.

Comment: Thank you, man! That works, I've removed my local DLL and load from NuGets, System.Linq.Dynamic.Core. Don't know why, but System.Linq.Dynamic lib don't work, but .Core is ok!